# How QGIS's "Remove duplicate nodes" actually works

Tags: qgis, geometry, polygon-creation, digitizing, duplicates

I am working on digitizing a large number of polygons using stream digitizing, which sometimes creates duplicate nodes. I noticed that in "Layer Properties>Digitizing>Automatic Fixes" you can check a box to "Remove duplicate nodes". After checking this, I see no visible difference, and I want to figure out if the duplicate nodes are actually being removed.

Does anyone have any information on how this actually works? When are the nodes removed?

Comment: Run the topology check. It it does not complain about duplicate nodes then they have removed (or they did not exist). You cannot see the difference, several vertices in a stack look the same as one vertex.

Comment: You can extract vertices and then set the layer rendering style to point cluster. Zoom in to see where you have more then one point in the same place: the point's symbol will be shown as a small circle with the number of points.